# Pandas Group by with Relational Operations

Tags: python, pandas

Sample

```
Electronics            Price

IPhone 11              500 

Iphone 11 pro          800

Iphone 11 pro max      1200

IPhone 11              550  

Iphone 11 pro          850

Samsung S 20           750

Iphone 11 pro max      1250

Samsung S 20 pro       1400

Samsung S 22           1000

Samsung S 20           800

Samsung S 20 pro       1350
```

How to Group by Electronics column and **then sum Price column**. Then print the Electronics name, which price in total more than 1200.

Output

```
Iphone 11 pro      1650

Iphone 11 pro max  2540

Samsung s 20       1550

Samsung s 20 pro   2750
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine a [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
out = df.groupby('Electronics', as_index=False).sum().query('Price > 1200')
```

Output:

```
         Electronics  Price
1      Iphone 11 pro   1650
2  Iphone 11 pro max   2450
3       Samsung S 20   1550
4   Samsung S 20 pro   2750
```